# Power analysis for an IPTW (Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting) model?

Tags: statistical-power, propensity-scores, weighted-regression, weighted-data

I have a sample of N=1,615, and 319 of those cases (19.75%) received the treatment. The prevalence of the outcome of interest is about 0.09 for the whole sample.

Ultimately, I want to conduct IPTW to estimate the association of the treatment with the outcome. This likely means that I have to trim the sample before doing the final analysis, but I have yet to create balanced groups or calculate weights. Suppose I have to drop 10% of cases to create matched samples, which would leave me with an N of 1,453.

There is a paper by [Austin (2021)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sim.9176) that explains how to do a power analysis in such a scenario, but it frankly goes over my head.

Suppose I want to see if my model will be able to detect a small effect size (e.g., an odds ratio of 1.5) at the 0.05 significance level with my sample of 1,453.

I attempted to do the power analysis using the R code below, but the estimated_power value I get is always either exactly 0 or exactly 1 (no matter how I change the specifications), which makes me thing that something's not right.

I'm also unsure how to best specify the VIF threshold.

```r
# Propensity score model
prop_score_model <- glm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 , 
        family = binomial(), data = df)
summary(prop_score_model)

# Parameters
num_simulations <- 99  # Number of simulations
vif_threshold <- 0.85  # Specify the VIF threshold 
                       # for significance
prevalence <- 0.09
alpha <- 0.05
effect_sizes <- c(1.25, 1.5, 6.0)  # Define a range 
                                   # of effect sizes
n <- nrow(df)  # You need to define the sample size 
               # based on your data

# Custom power analysis function
custom_power_analysis <- function(num_simulations, 
    prop_score_model, n, prevalence, alpha, 
    effect_size, vif_threshold) {
  # Initialize a variable to keep track of how often 
  # the effect is detected
  power_estimate <- 0
  
  for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
    # Calculate the VIF for the logistic regression 
    # model
    roc_obj <- pROC::roc(response = df$em, 
        predictor = predict(prop_score_model, 
        type = "response"))
    simulated_c_statistic <- pROC::auc(roc_obj)
    
    # Calculate the VIF using the formula you 
    # provided
    simulated_vif <- (1 + (n-1) * (1 - prevalence) * 
       (1 - simulated_c_statistic)) / 
       (n * prevalence * simulated_c_statistic)
    
    # Check if the effect is statistically 
    # significant based on the specified VIF 
    # threshold
    effect_detected <- simulated_vif < vif_threshold
    
    # If the effect is detected, increment the 
    # power_estimate variable
    if (effect_detected) {
      power_estimate <- power_estimate + 1
    }
  }
  
  # Calculate the estimated power as the proportion 
  # of times the effect was detected
  estimated_power <- power_estimate / num_simulations
  
  return(estimated_power)
}

# Call the custom_power_analysis function
estimated_power <- 
    custom_power_analysis(num_simulations, 
    prop_score_model, n, prevalence, alpha, 
    effect_size, vif_threshold)
print(estimated_power)
```

Comment: I want to start by thanking you for the interesting paper. It's quite useful for me personally. 
Now your question is also reasonable, but your code frankly  seems full of misconceptions. What is a VIF-threshold supposed to be? How could it be less than 1?
Also you don't simulate anything. You just do the same thing 99 times which is why you get 1 or 0, but that's not the important problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I figured that there are issues with my approach, but that's as close as I got to conduct my power analysis. Do you have any advice how to do this correctly?